# document.activeElement.matches(:focus) is false. why is this?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, dom, pseudo-class

I have an li:

```html
<li _ngcontent-c21="" class="accordion li" tabindex="0" aria-expanded="true">
```

Which I have tabbed to. document.activeElement is in fact this element. However,

```
document.activeElement.matches(':focus')
false
```

and to make matters even slightly more bizzare:

```
document.activeElement.focus()
undefined
document.activeElement.matches(':focus')
false
```

What is going on here? (this is chrome, btw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is happening in the console, the console is in focus, not the element or indeed the page; therefore, elements cannot match `:focus` as long as the console is in focus. This is not a limitation of `Element#matches()`, but a side effect of how `:focus` works — `:focus` CSS style rules behave the same way.

If you either set a timeout in the console and refocus the page before the timeout expires, or call these functions in a `<script>` within the page, `document.activeElement` should match `:focus` as expected.