# Why does document.activeElement.matches(':focus') return false?

Tags: javascript, dom, safari, webkit, onfocus

I have this snippet:

```js
function focusChanged(event)
{
//  setTimeout(function() {

  console.log('focus now: ' + document.activeElement);
  console.log(document.activeElement.matches(':focus'));

//}, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="editor one" contenteditable="true" onfocus="focusChanged(event)">click here to focus</div>
```

Without the timeout, the following returns `false`:

```
document.activeElement.matches(':focus')
false
```

The console is *not* open (as suggested in [document.activeElement.matches(:focus) is false. why is this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60740374/document-activeelement-matchesfocus-is-false-why-is-this))

This happens in WebKit/Safari. Can anybody explain why this is happening? Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Maybe some more background: I only discovered the above problem after running into a problem with jQuery's `.is(':focus')`. I have an old project that still uses jQuery v1.9.1.

This code: `$('.editor').is(':focus')` worked fine for years. Only with the latest update to macOS Catalina 10.15.4 did this start to return `false` even when the div has the focus. I then tried to use a vanilla JS solution and ran into the above issue.

Comment: FWIW, for lurkers: I can replicate the OP's results. Chrome shows `true` when you focus the element, Safari shows `false` (unless you add the `setTimeout`).

Answer (score 0):

Some events are implemented slightly differently across browsers. It would appear that on WebKit-based browsers, the element isn't considered "focussed" until after the event handlers have run, but on Blink-based browsers (Chrome, etc.), despite it being a fork of (part of) WebKit, it's considered focussed during the event handlers.

Your solution of allowing the event to complete seems like a solid workaround.